# Excel VBA keeping first 3 numbers within commas

Tags: vba, excel

I have thousands of lines of raw data I need to manipulate.

It looks something like:

```
001_sample.com, 002_XML3.com, 003_Example532.com
004_Example.com
005_Example392.com, 006_sample399.com
```

and so on..

I just need the first 3 numbers so I want to be left with.

```
001, 002, 003
004
005, 006
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I have tried the Mid and Left function but I cannot get it right.

This is what I was doing originally...

For Each c In Range("E1:E5000")

```
If InStr(c.value, "_") > 0 Then
    c.value = Left(c.value, InStr(c.value, "_") - 1)
End If
    If InStr(c.value, " ") > 0 Then
    c.value = Left(c.value, InStr(c.value, " ") - 1)
End If
```

Next c

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Please read [ask]. As it stands your question is pretty much "I have this data, I need XYZ, please do it for me". *Show us* what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty UDF that will do what you want:

```
Function mySplit(rng) As String
Dim splt() As String
Dim i As Integer
If rng.Count > 1 Then Exit Function
splt = Split(rng, ",")
For i = LBound(splt) To UBound(splt)
    splt(i) = Left(Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(splt(i)), 3)
Next
mySplit = Join(splt, ", ")

End Function
```

Put it in a module attached to the workbook then you would call it like a formula:

```
=mySplit(A1)
```

[image]

---

If you have Office 365 Excel then you can use this array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,LEFT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",999)),999*(ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1))-1)+1,999)),3))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting Edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott, works perfectly. How could I convert this to a subroutine?  In your example if I could run the program and have column C appear in column A without having to click and drag, that would be ideal.

Comment: Just create a subroutine that iterate through the range and call this function passing each range into it.  It will return a string that you then can assign anywhere you want.

Comment: How would that work within the "personal" workbook? When I ran the program outside of being within the personal workbook it worked fine, but when added to my main code I ran into issues.

Comment: That is a new question.  You would need to preface the call with the location of the code.  Google **call function from another workbook**.  Then ask a new question if you can't get that working.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help Scott. I figured it out! In the end I really just had to call the formula by =Personal.xlsb!mySplit(RC[-3])

Comment: @Jake please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify how the data is stored. If Cell A1 has the value, you can use this:

```
Dim value As String, numeric As String
value = Range("A1").Value
numeric = LEFT(value, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your datas are in column A, then it will work.

```
Sub test()
    Dim vDB, vR() As String, vSplit
    Dim rngDB As Range
    Dim n As Long, i As Long, j As Integer
    Set rngDB = Range("a1", Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) 'fix your column  a~~> your column
    vDB = rngDB
    n = UBound(vDB, 1)
    ReDim vR(1 To n, 1 To 1)
    For i = 1 To n
        vSplit = Split(vDB(i, 1), ",")
        For j = 0 To UBound(vSplit)
            vSplit(j) = Split(vSplit(j), "_")(0)
        Next j
        vR(i, 1) = Join(vSplit, ",")
    Next i
    rngDB = vR

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Dy.Lee, thank you for your help. I modified your example to fit my program. I have a question however, this code is only grabbing the first 3 digits and ignoring the rest. For example I am left with 001,, . I have tried to adjust the boundaries but I am only grabbing the first three numbers again. Do you have any recommendations for that?